# Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, ethernet, hard-drive

I wanted to create a Wifi to Ethernet Bridge on my Raspberry Pi, similar to [this one](http://www.instructables.com/id/Share-WiFi-With-Ethernet-Port-on-a-Raspberry-Pi/).
The problem is: I want to conntect a Network Harddrive (WD MyCloud) to the ethernet side. The Harddrive seems to have internet access from its side but I can't access the dashboard of it or mount to my computer.

What do I have to change that the RPi doesn't only give the Harddrive access to the internet but also give other devices in my network access to the Harddrive?

**Edit:** The Harddrive is a network harddrive that you just plug into ethernet and it connects to your network. I can see that it has network access because it has a blue LED on and not the red one it would have turned on if it didn't have network access. The Raspberry Pi is running stock Raspbian.

Comment: @Fabian The Harddrive is a network harddrive that you just plug into ethernet and it connects to your network. I can see that it has network access because it has a blue LED on and not the red one it would have turned on if it didn't have network access.
The Raspberry Pi is running stock Raspbian

Comment: This looks similar to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/51057/33476

Answer (score 16):

This is a common problem with tons of documentation on the web. A very informative discussion I've found on [<sup>**(1)**</sup>](https://serverfault.com/q/152363/458473). Be aware that this problem only belongs to a wifi client connection that you want to brigde with another wifi client connection to a remote access point (e.g. uplink to an internet router). Bridging an access point (**wlan0**/**ap0**) together with a wired or wireless uplink (**eth0**/**wlan0**) is possible.

In general there are mostly 3 ways you can "bridge" a wifi client interface.

**1. real bridging on OSI layer 2** would be the best solution. But wifi needs additional information in the ip header for this. Many router uses this for WDS (Wireless Distribution System) [<sup>**(2)**</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system) but need an additional address field enabled in the ip header. You usually can do this with:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on
```

But you will get the error message:

```
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

that just means what it say. The built-in wifi device of a Raspberry Pi does not support it [<sup>(6)</sup>](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/55731/79866). So you have to look for workarounds.

**2. NAT (Network Address Translation) on OSI layer 3**. This is what you have found and tried to setup. An alternative setup you can also find at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). But *@Thomas Guyot-Sionnest* commented [<sup>**(3)**</sup>](https://serverfault.com/a/863241/458473):

> 4addr as described in other answers is certainly the best way when
>   supported by the adapter/driver, but not all of them does. NAT might
>   work for some things, but getting proper communication both ways on
>   the lan will become problematic (ex. connecting a printer or accessing
>   other IoT devices on the other side of the NAT). Anything relying on
>   broadcast/multicast (ex. auto-discovery, bonjour) will fail through
>   the NAT.

Seems you are running into this trouble. I think the best alternative is to use

**3. Proxy ARP on OSI layer 3**. I suggest you look at [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88955/79866) and try it because:

> Using Proxy ARP permits the bridged clients to be part of the existing
>   network and supports bidirectional traffic, e.g. for a server or
>   printer. DHCP and mDNS will also work using the appropriate helpers [**<sup>(4)</sup>**](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp).

**references:**
[1] [Bridging wlan0 to eth0](https://serverfault.com/q/152363/458473)
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system
[3] https://serverfault.com/a/863241/458473
[4] https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp
[5] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model
[6] [Raspberry PI 3 MODEL B - Wireless Bridge to ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/55731/79866)

Comment: Hey @Ingo, really thorough answer! I have a bridge that currently links wlan0(input) to eth0 (output) but as you stated won't work for adding 4addr. Just purchased a USB-WiFi dongle that will work for 4addr (confirmed the command works), are there any other setup steps I need to ensure I'm getting a Layer 2 instead of Layer 3 bridge?

Comment: @cdubs I have to admit that I'm a bit out of the topic because of other projects. But I remember that I had verified the 4addr issue also with a dongle that supported it but can't remember details. For now I would try to setup a bridge as documented to connect two wired subnets and solve the problems step by step if possible.

Comment: no problem at all, thanks for the reply! I’ll see what I can come up with