# Bridge wlan0 <--> wlan1

Tags: wifi, bridge

Has anyone successfully configured a bridge between `wlan0` and `wlan1`?

On `wlan1` I have an internet connection with subnet `192.168.107.xxx`

At `wlan0` I would like to have an internet connection available with the address in the `192.168.107.xxx` subnet given by `wlan1`.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports wlan1
        address 192.168.107.13
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.107.0
        broadcast 192.168.107.255
```

And in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
bridge=br0
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=blablabla
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

/etc/default/hostapd 

DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Can anyone show me how to run it and is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the answer from *@Milliways* you have to enable `4addr` support on the wlan interfaces with `sudo iw dev wlanX set 4addr on`. But if you try to add such an interface to the bridge you will get the error message `Operation not permitted`. Raspberry Pi does not support OSI layer 2 bridging for client connections on wifi (an access point can be bridged). You have to use [workarounds for "bridging" wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866). You may consider to use `routing` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in futility. There are a number of problems.

1. Any attempt to configure `/etc/network/interfaces` will only work if you disable `dhcpcd`
2. Depending on what model Pi and what OS `wlan0` and `wlan1` are indeterminate.

You have not specified **what you are actually attempting to achieve** or what OS so your "question" is indeterminate.

It is **certainly POSSIBLE** to bridge interfaces, but not as described.

[Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `bridge_ports wlan1` to `bridge_ports wlan0 wlan1`to bind (or bridge) *wlan0* and *wlan1*.