# Make wifi onboard as an access point and wifi dongle as a client

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, wireless, access-point

I want to turn my raspberry pi 3 witch installed Raspbian OS to access point and client to access wifi and bridge these two each other (in this question it's better to skip this bridge part). Exactly, I want to change on-board Wi-Fi to access point and add a wifi dongle to raspberry pi 3 and get connected to some SSID.

I dig in the deep of the internet and try all solution that I find but none of them work correctly. Some time this two wifi worked great, but after each reboot because of priority of these two in load base system, all systems I work on it broke and no response.

Can you help me, how can I catch this situation and configure raspberry pi 3 to work this two wifi correctly beside each other and does not make a problem after each reboot or shutdown?

**UPDATE**

One of the best topics I found on the internet was this [link](https://scribles.net/creating-wireless-router-using-raspberry-pi-zero-w/), but unfortunately after while, its better say after each shutdown wlan0 and wlan1 broke some time and its not stable, again I search why its happening and find out, after each reboot or shutdown Linux system boot wifi dongle faster than wifi onboard and this case to break the configuration we made.

[Creating Wireless Router using Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://scribles.net/creating-wireless-router-using-raspberry-pi-zero-w/)

Comment: I find a repo that says you can use onboard wifi as an AP and Client, but this not works correctly and in the issues mention this problem.
https://github.com/cjimti/iotwifi

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a wifi client interface to a bridge. This must be supported by the wifi device with using WDS (wireless distribution service) but the Raspberry Pi hardware does not support it. For further information you can look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866). So we are limited to routing. I have made a configuration with a second wifi adapter used as access point. It's fairly simple with this additional hardware. But for your needs you only have to swap the interfaces **wlan0** and **wlan1** to make the on board wifi an access point. I think it shouldn't be to difficult. You can look at [RPI3 Raspbian Stretch regular connection on wlan0 AP on wlan1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88631/79866).

**update:**
I have just the idea that the second wifi usb dongle may be able to support WDS. On my wifi dongle I found a hint that that could be possible with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo iw list | less
```

In the pager I found on *Supported commands* for my dongle the command `set_wds_peer` which isn't available for the on board wifi device. So it is worth a try to `sudo iw dev wlan1 set 4addr on` and add **wlan1** as slave to a bridge. The interface from the on board wifi device can always added to a bridge when it is used for an access point. So it may be possible to have a real bridge but I haven't tried it yet.

**update 2:**
You wrote:

> Exactly, I want to change on-board Wi-Fi to access point and add a wifi dongle to raspberry pi 3 and get connected to some SSID.

This implies what is written: the WiFi dongle shall connect to a SSID given by a another remote access point, so it has to use a WiFi client connection to the other remote access point. Now you added a link, showing that the WiFi dongle should create an access point (not using a client connection). How to do it is easy. Just look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).

Comment: thanks for your answer, its better skip that bridge part and focuse on a solution to figure out how can I configure this two wifi work as an AP and Client.

Comment: update my question and add a link that really close to my question and solution i want to achieve.

Comment: @HosseinMarzban Your question was confusing. I have updated the answer with *update 2*.