# Bonding tor to wlan access point with systemd-networkd

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I have RPI3 with Raspbian 9 stretch in it,
I have an external wlan and I want to connect My home wifi with wlan1 then make hotspot with wlan0 and use tor as my network service,
I used to set up with hostapd and dnsmasq but after I see [**this**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/howto-migrate-from-networking-to-systemd-networkd-with-dynamic-failover) tutorial, I want do this with systemd-networkd without installing any other package,

I did step 1 to 3 of [**this**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/howto-migrate-from-networking-to-systemd-networkd-with-dynamic-failover) tutorial and connected my home wifi with wlan1

now what?:D

Comment: @ingo I didnt know how to contact you :D

Comment: I'm here. I will look, but seems not to be the easiest and I do not have installed tor before.

Comment: Does *external wlan* means that it is your home wifi with an internet router making the *external wlan*? The RPi 3B has built-in **eth0** and **wlan0**. You want to use an additional **wlan1**. This can only be done with an additional USB wifi dongle. Do you have one? With **wlan0** you will spawn an access point and with **wlan1** you will connect to your internet router and **eth0** isn't used. You will setup tor listening on **wlan0**. What shall tor do on the RasPi? Bonding is mainly used for failover and use redundant lines. What two lines should be bonded to what destination?

Comment: Instead of using an USB wifi dongle for **wlan1** you can also use a WiFi repeater but this is no longer bonding. Look at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). So what do you need?

Comment: @ingo yes I have and It works with hostapd and dnsmasq dhcpcd : http://bit.ly/2QKiAj0   torrc http://bit.ly/2QF1FhA  dnsmasq http://bit.ly/2QIWqxl   in my country half of sites are closed by government and half by world. I need tor to access social networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you have an additional USB wifi dongle for **wlan1** and uses it to connect to your home wifi from the internet router.

Then you use the built-in wifi device with interface **wlan0** to spawn an access point. On this interface is a tor router installed that routes trafic to the Tor network.

With this setup there is no way to use  bonding because lack of a second line for one connection to failover.

You can follow this answer to setup the client connection and the access point without installing additional software: [RPI3 Raspbian Stretch regular connection on wlan0 AP on wlan1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88631/79866). You only have to swap the interfaces.

If you have this running then it should not be difficult to install the tor router as you have already done. For doing it with *systemd-networkd* you can look at [How to make Raspberry Pi a Tor router with all kind of network setup using systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92296/79866).

Comment: I want share use wlan0 as hotspot, but i want share my tor network on it, i want make tor router

Comment: @SaebMolaee Sorry for confusing. I have changed the wording in my answer. You said you have already installed a tor router with dhcpcd, hostapd and dnsmasq. Just setup it the same way. I don't see a difference in the underlaying network configuration. There is a **wlan0** interface that's traffic can be routed to the Tor network. But I will test it. Just a moment please.

Comment: @SaebMolaee I have updated the answer with a link to a tor router setup.