# Trying to setup wifi ap and managed client mode together : sub-system time out on ap0

Tags: wifi, access-point

I followed the instructions here: [enter link description here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87504/raspberry-pi-zero-w-as-a-wifi-repeater/87506#87506) with the aim of getting ap and managed client wifi running together.  The  wlan0 setup works perfectly.  I could not see any attempt to run ap0 in the journalctl.

The command:

```
systemctl status wpa_supplicant@ap0.service
```

shows that ap0 is loaded but not active.

I ran the command:

```
sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant@ap0.service
```

The journal reported the following failure:

```
systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-ap0.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-ap0.device/start timed out.
```

Where should I look to solve this??

Comment: I have deleted the answer because it wasn't accepted. If you want to refer it, I have made a new one at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93636/79866).

Comment: All attempts to setup an AP with Stretch didn't work.  I tried again by upgrading Stretch to Buster.  Still didn't work.  I then tried to setup an AP with a fresh Buster installation and it worked perfectly first time.  I have decided not to try to setup in AP and client at the same time.