# Direct Ethernet IPCam and Wifi for browsing - Networking setup

Tags: networking, wifi, camera, ethernet

I would like to connect 2 ipcams via a switch to the RPI 3B+, and use the WiFi to connect to a router (to use the webbrowser etc), and also use the router for VNC

The ethernet is used to send commands to the camera and also watch the streams.

What is the best way to make this possible ?

Can I use the ethernet and WiFi at the same time ? Or do I need to set the switch to 192.168.2.xxx and the WiFi network at 192.168.1.xxx

Or do I need a separate DHCP server ?

[image: Networking image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be reduced to make the RasPi a router with an WiFi uplink to the local hotspot/router and connect to a local wired network. It is no problem to use the wired and wireless connection at the same time because you asked it. If you mean to have all devices on the same subnet 192.168.1.0/24 then it isn't possible. For this you have to use a bridge on the RasPi but the WiFi device on the RPi does not support bridging of a client connection. For further information look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866).

So you have to use routing with two different subnets and because you want to connect to the cams from outside the local wired LAN you cannot use NAT (Network Address Translation) to simplify configuration. You must configure your internet router with a static route to the wired network.

I will show how I would use routing to connect a wired ethernet interface to a remote hotspot via wifi with **systemd-networkd**. For reference I use [Raspbian Buster Lite 2019-07-10](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) updated with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo reboot` at 2019-08-25 on a Raspberry Pi 4B. It doesn't matter if there is a switch between the wired devices. I will only show one ipcam. More devices/cams will also work.

Example for this setup:

```
                                         laptop
        wired                      wifi   /        wan
ipcam <───────> (eth0)RPi(wlan0) <.~.~.~> hotspot <───> INTERNET
     \           /            \           ╲
    (dhcp   192.168.2.1   192.168.1.15   192.168.1.1
  from RPi)
```

Be sure that you do not use the same subnet for the wired LAN than the hotspot uses. Switch over to systemd-networkd:

```
# disable classic networking
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# systemctl mask networking.service dhcpcd.service
rpi ~# mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~
rpi ~# sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf

# enable systemd-networkd
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service
rpi ~# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Configure wpa_supplicant with your settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=`:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="TestNet"
    psk="Password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

Configure interfaces with this files:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Address=192.168.2.1/24
IPForward=yes
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.15/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

Reboot.

To get routing complete working you have to set a static route on your hotspot/internet router so it can find the route for back coming packages over the RasPi to the wired subnet. On most internet router you can set a static route but how to do that varies from model to model. It's up to you to find it out. For example your RasPi **wlan0** interface has the static ip address 192.168.1.15. Then on your router the gateway (next hop) is 192.168.1.15, destination network is 192.168.2.0/24 (or 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0).

That means for the internet router: "send all packages belonging to subnet 192.168.2.0/24 (wired subnet) to the next router on my subnet, the RasPi 192.168.1.15. It knows where to go on."

Comment: Is it also possible to completely block the ethernet side to the wireless side ; "internet" ? I would not like the cameras to access the local WiFi network

Comment: @Jeroen_13 Yes it is possible by using firewall **iptables** or policy routing. How do you want to send commands to the camera and also watch the streams? Only from the INTERNET and from devices connected to the switch?

Comment: I would like to use the raspberry PI with node.js to send commands to the camera's, use VLC on the PI to watch the streams, and use the laptop with VNC to do stuff on the PI, so I don't need a monitor. The PI just acts as a controller for the camera's, and I want to use the WiFi for VNC monitoring. That's why I don't want the camera's to access the rest of the network (including a NAS)

Comment: @Jeroen_13 OK, running things only from the RasPi makes it easy. Just deleting the line `IPForward=yes` in `/etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network` should do the job.