# Raspberry to act as a bridge/router (not as accesspoint) see details below

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+, pi-4

I am thinking of using a Raspberry 3b+ or pi 4 for the following project:
Overview: I need to send my wifi signal over a 100 m distance. However in order to do that, I first need to receive a wifi signal from my home router.
The way I am planning to achieve this is as follows:
1) use the pi to receive the wifi signal from the router
2) Send the signal over lan to a directional router/bridge/cpe such as the WIS-D5230 http://wisnetworks.com/web/index.php/product/productinfoen/94.html
3) Have devices connect wirelessly via the WIS-D5230.

My question is what kind of tools I would need to use to set up the pi to forward the signal from wifi (wifi being the internet side) to lan?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> what kind of tools I would need to use to set up the pi to forward the signal from wifi (wifi being the internet side) to lan?

In addition to the RasPi you do not need additional tools. The RasPi can connect to your WiFi access point and route the traffic through its wired ethernet port. The only thing you have to aware is that you must use routing because the RasPi cannot bridge the client WiFi interface **wlan0** with the wired interface **eth0**. So you will have a different subnet on the lan side. For example if your home network with the access point have the subnet 192.168.1.0/24 then on the lan side you may have 192.168.2.0/24. Here you can find a setup for an [RasPi as router with a WiFi uplink](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/101909/79866).