# unable to add wwan0 to bridge

Tags: networking, bridge, compute-module-3

I am trying to add the interface wwan0 to a bridge. Currently I am unable to do that.
When I run the command

```
brctl addif br0 wwan0

can't add wwan0 to bridge br0: Invalid argument
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?

edit 1:  I want to bridge wwan0 which is my 3g cellular dongle and Ethernet eth0.
I run the below command to get my wwan0 network activated.
`udhcpc -n -i wwan0`
Once I have successfully completed that.
I run the commands shown below.

`brctl addbr br0
 brctl addif br0 eth0`

The above commands complete without any issues. Then I try running 
`brctl addif br0 wwan0`

thats when I get the error `can't add wwan0 to bridge br0: Invalid argument`

I am using a kernel version of 4.19

Comment: Have you defined wwan0 anywhere (WiFi is normally on wlan0) and normally the brctl command needs two adapters e.g. eth0 and wlan0 etc.

Comment: @Andyroo I haven't defined it manually. But I do create a wwan0 by running `udhcpc -n -i wwan0`

Comment: So you need to tell the bridge which two networks you are wanting to bridge...

Comment: For what do you need the **wwan0** interface? Where do you get the command `udhcpc`? For what do you need it? What operating system do you use?  On my default Raspbian Buster Light there isn't it available (`sudo: udhcpc: command not found`).

Comment: @Ingo I think you have to download a package to get that. Having said that are you able to run the command `brctl addif br0 wwan0`

Comment: @Andyroo I have edited my question. Maybe that should explain the issue a little better. I am trying to add `wwan0` to my bridge `br0`. I am able to add `eth0` to `br0` but not `wwan0`

Comment: I would have thought the `brctl addif br0 wwan0 eth0` command would have done it though you may have to remove eth0 first.  What OS are you trying to run on the board?

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that the linux bridge does not accept all interfaces, in particular WiFi interfaces to be used for a client connection to an uplink router if it does not support WDS (Wireless Distribution Service) with `4addr`. For further information you can look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866). OK, this does not fit exactly your situation but may give you an idea what could be wrong. Check if the interface is known as a WiFi interface and if it supports WDS then. If the bridge does not accept the **wwan0** interface you have to use routing.